# Expressing the double integral of cosh(xy) over [0,1]×[0,1] as a convergent sequence

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

One of my homework questions asks for the expression of $$\iint_R \cosh xy \,dxdy\text{, where } R= [0,1] \times [0,1]$$ as a convergent sequence.  I began by computing the double integral normally and ended up with $$\int_0^1\frac{\sinh y}{y}\,dy = \int_0^1\frac{e^y-e^{-y}}{2y}\,dy.$$
How would I go about computing this integral?  It looks like something I would continuously apply integration by parts to and thereby yield an infinite series, so if that's right, what would be good choices for $u$ and $dv$?  If not, what should I do?  (I used Wolfram Alpha to compute this integral and it resulted in something called Shi($x$)," which, after further research, looks like something I should run from like the plague.)

Furthermore, I'm suspecting that this question might have a typo, as it makes sense for the integral to be a convergent *series*, but what would it mean to express it as a convergent sequence (it did *not* say to express it as the limit of such a sequence)?

Comment: A number is not a sequence, but it could be the limit of a sequence.    Presumably that is what is meant (and in particular, the sequence of partial sums of a series...)

Comment: Yeah, my friend and I were scratching our heads over the wording of this question.  The book I'm using (Vector Calculus, by Marsden) is reported to have several mistakes, so I'm not too surprised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Maclaurin expansion of $\sinh{y}$ is (as you can see from the exponential form)
$$ \sinh{y} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{y^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}. $$
This expansion is uniformly convergent on $[0,1]$, so you can just swap the sum and the integral, to get
$$ \int_0^1 \frac{\sinh{y}}{y} \, dy = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k+1)!} \int_0^1 y^{2k} \, dy, $$
and I'm sure you can see what happens after that.

Comment: Huh, never thought of it like that.  Thanks!  So do you think the question was asking for a series and not a sequence?

Comment: OK, thanks everyone!